# Python dns resolver print all results for a domain in the same line

Tags: python, multithreading, dns

I am new to python. I am trying to use dns.resolver module in my program, where I pass a list of domains and run them with a pool of threads that reads the contents of the file  asynchronously and then prints the results for each domain from the file.

Below is the code :

```
import dns.resolver
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
pool_size =4
pool = Pool(pool_size)
dnsResolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
dnsResolver.timeout = 1
dnsResolver.lifetime = 1
dnsResolver.nameservers = ['172.31.0.2']

#domain_list = ['google.com','facebook.com', 'amazon.com']
#for domain in domain_list:
# Query results for the dig operations from a file that contains less than 1024 domains in it 

def fetch_dig_no_blast_results(no_blast_domains):
 try:
  no_blast_domains = no_blast_domains.strip()
  dnsAnswer = dnsResolver.query(no_blast_domains)
  for rdata in dnsAnswer:
   print (no_blast_domains, "resolved to",str(rdata))
 except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
  print ("No records exists for", no_blast_domains)
 except dns.resolver.Timeout:
  print ("Timeout in querying",no_blast_domains)

with open("no-blast-domains.txt",'r') as fd1:
 for no_blast_domains in fd1:
  pool.apply_async(fetch_dig_no_blast_results, (no_blast_domains,))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I have two questions.

1. I need to print all the results of a dns query for a particular domain in the same line. For example, dns query for a domain 'amazon.com' gives three ip's. I need to print those three ip's in the same line -

example that output I am looking at is something like :

```
['amazon.com' resolved to 'ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']
```

Current code prints them in three lines

```
['amazon.com' resolved to 'ip1']

['amazon.com' resolved to 'ip2']

['amazon.com' resolved to 'ip3']
```

2. I want to make sure that each thread queries a different domain and no threads queries the same domain.

Any suggestions would immensely help me out.

Comment: you have to put results in list or dictionary and print after you get all results. This way you can create string with all IPs in one line.

Comment: you can create list with "visited" domains and check domain in the list before you use thread

Comment: Can someone provide an example as I m not able to get them working

Answer (score 1):

Replace these two lines of code in your example:

```
for rdata in dnsAnswer:
   print (no_blast_domains, "resolved to",str(rdata))
```

with (if you have integers/numbers in your list):

```
print(no_blast_domains, "resolved to", ",".join(str(x) for x in rdata))
```

with (if you have you only have strings in your list):

```
print(no_blast_domains, "resolved to", ",".join(rdata))
```